# Java-контейнер: множество элементов по одному ключу

Tags: java

Подскажите контейнер, куда можно положить такие значения:

- key1 value1
- key1 value2
- key1 value3
- key2 value4
- key2 value5
- key3 value6

То есть чтобы по одному ключу в нем можно было хранить множество элементов.

Comment: а чем мапа не подошла: `Map<KeyType, List<Value>>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Google Guava есть такое, [MultiMap](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap)

Answer (score 2):

В стандартной библиотеке Java нет multimap (которая есть в STL C++). В [статье](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) описано как можно сделать такую самому

Answer (score -1):

Ну, можно, например так поступить - реализовать класс, с полями key и value.
Дальше, просто в любой нужный( или удобный ) Вам контейнер пихать объекты этого класса.